# Rails custom font does not work for both firefox & IE

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts

I am trying to use the SegoePrint font on my rails app. I have in app/assets/fonts both files

> SegoePrint.ttf
>
> SegoePrint.eot

In my stylesheets if I have

```
@font-face {
font-family: "SegoePrint";        
src: url(SegoePrint.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

It works only for firefox, not for IE but if I have

```
@font-face {
font-family: "SegoePrint";        
src: url(SegoePrint.ttf) format("truetype");
src: url(SegoePrint.eot);
src: url(SegoePrint.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype");
}
```

I works only for IE and not for firefox anymore. What is the right syntax to have it work for both browsers please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about if you using this syntax below

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SegoePrint';
    src: asset-url('SegoePrint.eot');
    src: asset-url('SegoePrint.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         asset-url('SegoePrint.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```